# search for meta_key and get its meta_value inside stdclass

Tags: php

I'm using this PHP code to filter an stdclass array:

```
    function filter_callback($element) {
      if (isset($element->meta_key) && $element->meta_key == '_vendor_page_slug') {
        Return true;
      }
    }
    $arr = array_filter($results5, 'filter_callback');
```

This code will return something like this:

```
Array
(
[22] => stdClass Object
    (
        [umeta_id] => 1784
        [user_id] => 10
        [meta_key] => _vendor_page_slug
        [meta_value] => Adidas
    )

)
```

now I want to get only "Adidas" without using 22.
I mean i don't want to use `$arr[22]->meta_value` because if this (22) number changes I couldn't get meta_value.
I also don't want to use foreach and also tried `$arr->meta_value`.
Actually I think the best way should be changing 'filter_callback' function, but I don't know how.

ThankYou SoMuch.

Comment: Aside: your filter should just return true for values you want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only one element:

```
echo current($arr)->meta_value;
//or
echo reset($arr)->meta_value;
```

Or `array_pop` or `array_shift`.  Either way you might want to check that it's not empty first.